# How to Save Textboxt.Text as file name?

Tags: vb.net

What's wrong with this code?

I need to add `textbox13.text` (the value of it is in number) as the file name and how can I add an option which checks if the file already exists if so show an option saying replace or cancel when I press my save button.

So far here is the code :

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim filepath As String = IO.Path.Combine("D:\Logs", Textbox13.Text + i.ToString() + ".txt")        
Using sw As New StreamWriter(filepath)
sw.WriteLine(TextBox13.Text)
sw.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
sw.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text)
sw.WriteLine(TextBox3.Text)
sw.WriteLine(TextBox4.Text)
sw.WriteLine(TextBox5.Text)

sw.WriteLine(TextBox7.Text)

sw.WriteLine(TextBox9.Text)
sw.WriteLine(TextBox10.Text)
sw.WriteLine(TextBox11.Text)
sw.WriteLine(TextBox12.Text)
```

This is from Form1

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Form2.WriteTextBoxTextToLabel(TextBox1.Text)
    Form2.WriteTextBoxTextToTextbox(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

This is from form2

```
Public Sub WriteTextBoxTextToLabel(ByVal Txt As String)
    lblPD.Text = Txt
End Sub
Public Sub WriteTextBoxTextToTextbox(ByVal Txt As String)
    TextBox13.Text = Txt
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox13_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox13.TextChanged
    TextBox13.Text = lblPD.Text

End Sub
```

Comment: I have reverted the last edit, as we don't use [solved] title hacks here, nor do we add solution material as an addendum. Self-answers that build on the existing answer are very welcome though - please add an answer below (i.e. not in the question or comments). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following logic before creating the `StreamWriter`:

```
if system.io.file.exists(filepath) then
   ' The file exists
else
   ' The file does not exist
end if
```

Comment: Thank you but what about save my file as the text in textbox13.text ?

Comment: You're already including the value of `Textbox13.Text` in your file path, no?

Comment: yes i am but its not saving as the textboxt text 
error message (System.ArgumentException: 'Illegal characters in path.')

Comment: btw the textbox13.text is generated from another textbox

Comment: its from form1 textbox and generated to form2 lable and then the lable.text is generated to textbox13.text which is in form 2

Comment: this is from Form 1 code 

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Form2.WriteTextBoxTextToLabel(TextBox1.Text)
        Form2.WriteTextBoxTextToTextbox(TextBox1.Text)
    End Sub


This is from form 2 code 

    Public Sub WriteTextBoxTextToLabel(ByVal Txt As String)
        lblPD.Text = Txt
    End Sub
    Public Sub WriteTextBoxTextToTextbox(ByVal Txt As String)
        TextBox13.Text = Txt
    End Sub

Comment: For security sake, you shouldn't let the user enter the filename freely. You should at least check whether it contains illegal characters.

Comment: Check my update i Added to form1 Textboxt1.text to allow only to write numbers on the textbox
Still doesnt save data

Comment: nvm now it saves data thx but doesnt show to overwrite the data when same number is input to textbox13.text

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, please upvote and choose as correct answer.